# For loop not scraping all items, just one

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to webscrape a page with about 20 articles, but for some reason the spider is only finding the information needed for the very first article. How do I make it scrape every article on the page?

I've tried changing the xpaths multiple times, but I think that I'm too new to this to be sure what the issue is. When I take all the paths out of the for loop it scraps everything well, but its not in a format that allows me to transfer the data to a csv file.

```
import scrapy


class AfgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'afg'
    allowed_domains = ['www.pajhwok.com/en']
    start_urls = ['https://www.pajhwok.com/en/security-crime']

    def parse(self, response):
        container = response.xpath("//div[@id='taxonomy-page-block']")
        for x in container:
            title = x.xpath(".//h2[@class='node-title']/a/text()").get()
            author = x.xpath(".//div[@class='field-item even']/a/text()").get()
            rel_url = x.xpath(".//h2[@class='node-title']/a/@href").get()
        


            yield{
                'title' : title,
                'author' : author,
                'rel_url' : rel_url
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice answer provided by @Roman. Another options to fix your script :

.Declaring the right XPath for your loop step :

```
container = response.xpath("//div[@class='node-inner clearfix']")
```

. Or, remove your loop step and use `.getall()` method to fetch the data :

```
title = response.xpath(".//h2[@class='node-title']/a/text()").getall()
author = response.xpath(".//div[@class='field-item even']/a/text()").getall()
rel_url = response.xpath(".//h2[@class='node-title']/a/@href").getall()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to collect required information:

```py
import scrapy


class AfgSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['www.pajhwok.com/en']
    start_urls = ['https://www.pajhwok.com/en/security-crime']

    def parse(self, response):
        container = response.css("div#taxonomy-page-block div.node-article")
        for x in container:
            title = x.xpath(".//h2[@class='node-title']/a/text()").get()
            author = x.xpath(".//div[@class='field-item even']/a/text()").get()
            rel_url = x.xpath(".//h2[@class='node-title']/a/@href").get()

            yield{
              'title': title,
              'author': author,
              'rel_url': rel_url
            }
```

The problem was that you code `container = response.xpath("//div[@id='taxonomy-page-block']")`

returns only one row, it's because `id` should be unique within the whole page, `class` can be the same for a few tags